# CSS: Irregular Grid Layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an irregular grid layout using CSS. Here's my Jfiddle so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/F94gu/1/

Code:

HTML:

```
<div style="width:275px;">
     <div class="box" id="box1"></div>
     <div class="box" id="box2"></div>
     <div class="box" id="box4"></div>
     <div class="box" id="box5"></div>
     <div class="box" id="box3"></div>
     <div class="box" id="box6"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box { margin: 2px; float:left; }
#box1 { height: 86px; width:  80px; background-color: red;}
#box2 { height: 42px; width:  161px; background-color: green;}
#box3 { height: 42px; width:  80px; background-color: blue;}
#box4 { height: 86px; width:  80px; background-color: orange;}
#box5 { height: 129px; width: 80px; background-color: yellow;}
#box6 { height: 42px; width:  161px; background-color: brown;}
```

What I'm trying to do is move the blue block up (directly underneath the red block), which would allow the brown block to move to the left and up. Below is an image of how it currently looks vs what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Hope this is enough information, I'd be happy to clarify if you need more information. I'm aware that the pixels are slightly off, it's about a quarter of the size of what I'm looking for so I divided all of my pixel definitions by 4, which lead to some decimals which I just ignored (and causes the lines to not match up perfectly).

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: I'd prefer a way to do this in pure CSS, if possible. I do appreciate the library, though, and I'll look into it if I can't find a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/F94gu/2/

''Dirty'' solution, with negative margins, but...

```
  .box { margin: 2px; float:left; }

    #box1 { height: 86px; width:  80px; background-color: red;}
    #box2 { height: 42px; width:  161px; background-color: green;}
    #box3 { height: 42px; width:  80px; background-color: blue;margin-top:-87px;}
    #box4 { height: 86px; width:  80px; background-color: orange;}
    #box5 { height: 129px; width: 80px; background-color: yellow;}
    #box6 { height: 40px; width:  163px; background-color: brown;margin-top:-42px;}
```

Comment: Is this solution "dirty" only because it's ugly, or does it yield some kind of compatibility problems or something? On the whole I think it's perfect, it works just like it should

Comment: It is not dirty, negative margins are not evil. Is your content static? This is the best option.

Comment: My content is text, which I will style (and limit in length) via CSS/PHP, so although it's not actually static, it might as well be.

Answer (score 0):

Please use: http://masonry.desandro.com/

It will save you a ton of time.

Comment: But it adds a lot of weight. Anyway is the best solution if your content isn't static and you can't handcode it..

Answer (score -1):

you should set position as absolute for each box and then position using left right.

Answer (score -2):

This is not a solution IMO. Why not using a real grid directive in CSS?

You can even make it responsive if you want. I've done it a lot of times and it works cross browser.

https://grid.layoutit.com/

Comment: This question is from 2014, the URL you posted appeared in 2019 according to the Wayback Machine. The CSS grid itself was implemented around 2017 (https://alistapart.com/article/the-story-of-css-grid-from-its-creators/). That's the answer to your "why not" - you've necro'd an old question.