# How to focus on one column independently of other columns or rows

Tags: css

I am trying to find out if there is a way to focus on a single column independently of other columns or rows.

I have searched the forums and I've got this code so far, but it only changes all columns indepently, I am trying to achieve something like this: [Image](https://www.screencast.com/t/GNJODhIG3)

The code I am using is this:

```
.column.size-1of3:nth-child(1) {
    width: 50% !important;
}
```

Any help would be much apreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want a structure like the image???

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do:
For css:

```
table{
    border: 2px solid blue; /*just to be easier to see*/
}
td, th {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid red; /*just to be easier to see*/
}
```

For HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

You can change the th to td if you want to and it should work the same way.

Comment: Please :*-( NO table layout when we have `display: grid`

Answer (score 0):

Partho63, yes the image is the layout I'm trying to get.

Darius Biro, thanks, this could work but I am trying to style a post feed module and I only have a class to work with.

I have found this code to create 4 columns, but I don't think I can isolate just one column.

```
@media only screen and ( min-width: 981px ) {
#page-container .et_pb_salvattore_content[data-columns]::before {
content: '4 .column.size-1of4' !important;
}
/* These are the classes that are going to be applied: */
#page-container  .column { float: left !important; }
.size-1of4 { width: 22% !important; margin-left: 1% !important;}}
```

I have looked online and I've come across these tutorials which use CSS grids, so I think this will work.

https://divisoup.com/how-to-use-css-grid-with-divis-feed-modules/
[CSS: Irregular Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546149/css-irregular-grid-layout)

So I can use the following which will add CSS grid to my post feed, but I can't find out how to span across several cells independently?

```
    .ds-grid-blog .et_pb_ajax_pagination_container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 18%);
    grid-column-gap: 2.5%;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at some nice [CSS Grid tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) (especially on `grid-area` property) and perhaps you'll be able to come up with something like this:

```
.ds-grid-blog .et_pb_ajax_pagination_container > article:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: 1/1/2/3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ludovit Mydla.. I checked out the link and a few others, unfortunately becuase I am tryign to style a post feed module, I can only assign one class, all the references I can find advise to create classes for the grid cells, then style with a formula,, but I only have one class to style with.... I have looked into nth-child styling, but as of yet cannot find a formula that works,, I see you've mentioned that in your answer, do you know if it would work with this post feed module http://mediaworldwide.co.uk/perfect-storm/ams-test-site/news ? Thanks